# Espresso Matcher for Nested RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, ui-testing

So here's a breakdown of my hierarchy:

```
RecyclerView --> LinearLayout --> RecyclerView --> FrameLayout -> FrameLayout
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: layout]

I would like to be able to verify the `FrameLayout` with the text is displayed. This what I have tried so far:

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.container_list).atPositionOnView(0, R.id.row_content))
                .check(matches(withRecyclerView(R.id.row_content).atPositionOnView(0, R.id.info_field)))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

But it causes an `AmbiguousViewMatcherException`. Any ideas on how to verify that nested view? Should mention I'm using the ViewMatcher from [here](https://github.com/dannyroa/espresso-samples/blob/master/RecyclerView/app/src/androidTest/java/com/dannyroa/espresso_samples/recyclerview/RecyclerViewMatcher.java). Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was able to verify it using the explanation @manidesto provided above with some slight changes.

```
onView(allOf(isDescendantOfA(withRecyclerView(R.id.container_list).atPosition(0)),
                isDescendantOfA(withRecyclerView(R.id.row_content).atPosition(0)),
                withId(R.id.info_field)))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Main enhancement is I used the `allOf` matcher to specify multiple characteristics of the view I was trying to verify.

Comment: How would you test click on the item inside the 2nd recyclerview?

Comment: As mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62750213/how-to-test-nested-recyclerview-recyclerview-inside-recyclerview-with-espresso this code only works with 0 value for atPosition.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.container_list).atPositionOnView(0, R.id.row_content))
    .check(matches(withChild(withId(R.id.info_field))))
```

This just checks whether the `View(R.id.row_content)` has a child with id `R.id.info_field`

#### Note:

`.check()` takes in a `ViewAssertion` which means that the `view` matched by your `ViewMatcher` given to the  `onView()` method is just asserted by the `ViewAssertion`

So when you do

```
onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.container_list).atPositionOnView(0, R.id.row_content))
    .check(matches(withChild(withId(R.id.info_field))))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
```

the `ViewMatcher` - `isDisplayed()` is applied to `R.id.row_content` matched inside `onView()` not the `R.id.info_field` asserted to matching in `.check()` call

Comment: This new edit doesn't work because of the `withChild` inside of the `check` method.

Comment: sorry. I missed a `matches()`

Comment: @adavis hope you find the note useful

Comment: yes, thanks for your explanation, that helped me focus on the issue better!